# Why is the following code with strings generating a bus error when called from a function?

Tags: c, string, runtime-error

I've figured this out but I thought I might post it here in case it should help someone else.

So I have this code which reads an arbitrary about of data from a file and prints out the first string it finds (terminated by null). It appears to work fine if I use the code directly in the function, but returning the string always seems to result in a bus error if I use the string after capturing the return value.

```
static char *read_string(FILE *obj_file, off_t offset, size_t size) {
char *strraw = load_bytes(obj_file, offset, size);
char* str = malloc(size);
strcpy(str, "");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (strraw[i] == '\0') {
        strncpy(str, strraw, i + 1);
        break;
    }
}
free(strraw);
return str;
```

}

Elsewhere:

```
char *string = *read_string(obj_file, absoluteOffset, 1024);
printf("  The String: %s\n", string);
free(string);
```

If I comment out the printf it runs fine, but if I attempt to use it I get that bus error. This function is following a similar design for another function I made which does similar string work just without reading anything from a file.

Comment: `strncpy(str, strraw, i);` ? Why is there a `i` as the 3rd argument? What is the point of that loop - isn't it just `strcpy`? Or `strncpy(str, strraw, size)`.

Comment: So in this sample it only is intended to get a single string, but I wrote with the intent to get several strings. The idea being I would get a block of bytes and return all the null terminated strings in it. And that was where I was headed when I stumbled across this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the question above is that function called below was prefixed with a *.

This resulted in the returned value being dereferenced (which was not my intention), the dereference of the returned value resulted in only a single character being returned which caused the bus error when it was attempted to be used with printf which expected a null terminated string but it only received a single character.

The way this function should have been called is without the * as shown below.

```
char *string = read_string(obj_file, absoluteOffset, 1024);
printf("  The String: %s\n", string);
free(string);
```

Comment: The function wasn't "defined with a `*`" (that's meaningless). The `*` is part of the return type (`char *`).

Comment: Please double check the original question, the faulty code had a * preceeding the function name when called. char *string = *read_string(...), there was never an issue with the return value definition.

Comment: I'm not talking about return values either. You're explanation that the function was "defined" with a `*` is meaningless. The function is declared with a return type that happens to be a pointer. The "dereferenced unexepectedly" part of your answer is no good either. If you dereference something in your code (be it a variable or the return value of a function), well, yes the compiler will emit code to dereference it. Nothing unexpected. All in all the answer is confusing.

Comment: My apologies, I'd love to have a better understanding of what actually went wrong. I'm happy to update the answer if you can help me understand exactly what placing the * infront of the called function actually did.

Comment: When you declared a function `char *something(int a, float b)`, it is parsed as `(char *) something(...)`. That `*` belongs to the return type. You're not declaring a function `*something` that returns a `char`, you're declaring a function `something` that returns a `char *`. When you call `something(42, 3.14)` you get back a value of type `char *`. If you dereference that (`*something(42, 3.14)`), you get a single char.

Comment: So it was that single char (without the null I assume) which caused the issue?

Comment: The issue is that what you had is essentially equivalent to if you had written `char *string = 'a';` - you're casting a char to a pointer which is meaningless (undefined behavior follows). Your compiler should have told you something was wrong if you had warnings enabled high enough.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation @Mat I've updated my answer with the details, please let me know if I missed anything. You were very helpful! :-)

Comment: @JoshuaBriefman There’s another error in your code: the `strncpy` command fails to copy the string-ending null byte. The string has `i` characters, indexed `0` through `i-1`. The byte after that, with index `i`, is the null byte. The command copies `i` bytes, i.e. only the characters. Since `malloc` doesn’t fill the allocated memory with zeros, the returned string may not have a proper ending. That could also trip up `printf`.

Comment: Thanks Jim! I've updated the code to copy the extra null character, can't believe I missed that. I also added a strcpy of "" incase there is no null in the dataset since malloc doesn't initialize the memory.